I Am using Sanity and facing this issue
I am making my portfolio site. In it I have used sanity for CMS, NOw after making schemas and installing next-sanity, whenever I try to fetch data by importing createClient it showing me the below error:
Failed to compile
./node_modules/valibot/dist/index.js
Error: Failed to recognize value undefined for property Extended_Pictographic.
at Array.map ()
at Array.forEach ()
This error occurred during the build process and can only be dismissed by fixing the error.
Please help me find out to resolve this issue.
I have tried almost which chatgpt or other ai suggest, I have update the dependices, installed the valibot and many more but still it not moving forward.
